# Putting alternative text after every third post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a `WordPress` site for the first time and having some issues figuring out how to achieve what I am aiming for. I would like for it to display a banner advertisement after every third post then continue from where it left off in my existing post.

Because I probably worded this poorly I will display an example image below.

[image]

Here's the current loop file I am using within my `index.php` file.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

<?php 

    $title = htmlentities(get_the_title ()); 
    $str = explode ("&amp;#8211;", $title);

    $artist = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[0]);
    $song = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[1]);

?>
<div class="album-meta" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
    <div class="cover">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #757575"><img width="90px" height="90px" src="<?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); echo ''.$feat_image.''; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
    </div>
<div class="metadata">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #757575"><p><i style="font-size: 13.7px;"><?php print $song; ?></i></p>
    <p><strong style="font-size: 15px;"><?php print $artist; ?></strong></p>
    </a>
    <p><a href="http://linkshrink.net/zPog=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: #fff; background: #4E76C9; width: 200px; height: 50px;padding:  5px;line-height: 50px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold; border: none;text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #3170DD;box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #3170DD;border-radius: 3px 3px; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;">Download</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>



<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>



<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Just count the posts using `$i=0` at the start and `$i++` in your loop. And then you simply use `if ($i % 3)` to see if you should show an advertisement.

Comment: @jornane I am extremely unsure of how to edit this into the loop.. I have been reading about the loop since you commented but still completely unsure about how to edit it without it messing up..

Comment: @Ritzy In style of what you're doing, I'd let `the_post` increment and make an `post_advertisement` that does the check. Not really sure how your `have_posts` works though so I might be wrong here.

Comment: @jornane How ever I am doing this is not working.. so it seems that your method does work for standard PHP if I feed it randomly through another CMS however I'm not capable of getting it to work with WordPress.. could you provide a snippet of code as an answer for me to take a look at what I could possible be doing wrong ?

Comment: Ah, missed the Wordpress part, sorry. Then just set `$i=0` in the beginning, `$i++` before the end and the if somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
<?php $i = 0; // create a counter?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

<?php 

    $title = htmlentities(get_the_title ()); 
    $str = explode ("&amp;#8211;", $title);

    $artist = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[0]);
    $song = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[1]);

?>
<div class="album-meta" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
    <div class="cover">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #757575"><img width="90px" height="90px" src="<?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); echo ''.$feat_image.''; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="metadata">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #757575"><p><i style="font-size: 13.7px;"><?php print $song; ?></i></p>
        <p><strong style="font-size: 15px;"><?php print $artist; ?></strong></p>
        </a>
        <p><a href="http://linkshrink.net/zPog=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: #fff; background: #4E76C9; width: 200px; height: 50px;padding:  5px;line-height: 50px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold; border: none;text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #3170DD;box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #3170DD;border-radius: 3px 3px; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;">Download</a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php if($i%3 ==0 && $i >0){ // check you reached to third div or not?>
<!-- write the html of advertisement div ------->
<?php $i++;} ?> <!-- increase counter -->
<?php endwhile; else : ?>



<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>



<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This method is exactly how I was doing it, but it just returns the `html` after every post instead of after every third post.

Comment: Nevermind found the solution! it was because I had it set to display only two post on my index page for what ever reason, thank you very much Anant!

Comment: In the above code, First time "advertisement div" will display, So we need to add one condition for avoiding first time code.

if($i%3 ==0 && $i 1= 0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<?php 

$counter = 0;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

<?php 

    $title = htmlentities(get_the_title ()); 
    $str = explode ("&amp;#8211;", $title);

    $artist = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[0]);
    $song = preg_replace('#\[[a-zA-Z].*\]#','',$str[1]);

if($counter == 3){ ?>

********** Advertisement code write here ***********
<?php 
}


?>
<div class="album-meta" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;">
    <div class="cover">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #757575"><img width="90px" height="90px" src="<?php $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); echo ''.$feat_image.''; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"></a>
    </div>
<div class="metadata">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #757575"><p><i style="font-size: 13.7px;"><?php print $song; ?></i></p>
    <p><strong style="font-size: 15px;"><?php print $artist; ?></strong></p>
    </a>
    <p><a href="http://linkshrink.net/zPog=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="color: #fff; background: #4E76C9; width: 200px; height: 50px;padding:  5px;line-height: 50px;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold; border: none;text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #3170DD;box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #3170DD;border-radius: 3px 3px; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;">Download</a>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
$counter++;
endwhile; else : ?>
```